# Filter the regular price of woocommerce products

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic

Want to filter the regular price of woocommerce products.

Based on product id and their meta data I want filter the get_regular_price of that product

Something like this.

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_regular_price( $array, $int, $int ) { 

    return $array; 
} 


add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_regular_price', 'filter_woocommerce_get_regular_price', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: you have 3 filters for that `woocommerce_product_get_price`, `woocommerce_product_get_sale_price` and `woocommerce_product_get_regular_price`, each have `($price, $product)` as arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the filter hook "woocommerce_get_regular_price" is not usable any more. There is another one alternative of that, you can use this below code to achieve your need.

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_regular_price( $price, $product ) { 

    // use $product->get_id() to get product ID
    // Do any custom logical action

    return $price; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'filter_woocommerce_get_regular_price', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Will  this work if I am getting the regular price like this `$prod_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);`

Comment: Price is on the argument, Just use `$price` to take it inside the function

Comment: No , you did not get my point. Will your filter work for this as well `$prod_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true);` . It won't obviously because because its filter for `get_regular_price` function right ?

Comment: Yes, when you use `get_post_meta()` it will avoid all filters

Comment: Ohk so I have change all the get_post meta to get_regular_price . Thanks